# Unable to display multiple series in Syncfusion Flutter Charts

Tags: flutter, syncfusion

**Scenario**

I need to display three series in the form of an Area chart in my app. It should look like the following.

[image]

**Code**

I am using **syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^22.2.8**

I have a model as follows:

```
class ChartSampleData {
  int x;
  double y;
  double y2;
  double y3;
  ChartSampleData({
    required this.x,
    required this.y,
    required this.y2,
    required this.y3,
  });
}
```

I have populated a `chartData` list as follows:

```
List<ChartSampleData>? chartData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    chartData = <ChartSampleData>[
      ChartSampleData(x: 0, y: 1, y2: 1, y3: 1),
      ChartSampleData(x: 5, y: 1.1, y2: 1.2, y3: 1.3),
      ChartSampleData(x: 10, y: 1.21, y2: 1.44, y3: 1.69),
      ChartSampleData(x: 15, y: 1.33, y2: 1.73, y3: 2.20),
    ];
  }
```

And finally, I have a `SfCartesianChart` widget as follows:

```
SfCartesianChart(
                          plotAreaBorderWidth: 0,
                          primaryYAxis:
                              NumericAxis(minimum: 1, isVisible: false),
                          primaryXAxis: NumericAxis(isVisible: false),
                          // palette: const [
                          //   AppColors.primary30,
                          //   AppColors.primary50,
                          //   AppColors.primary100,
                          // ],
                          series: <ChartSeries<ChartSampleData, int>>[
                            AreaSeries(
                              dataSource: chartData!,
                              xValueMapper: (ChartSampleData data, _) => data.x,
                              yValueMapper: (ChartSampleData data, _) => data.y,
                              color: AppColors.primary100,
                            ),
                            AreaSeries(
                              dataSource: chartData!,
                              xValueMapper: (ChartSampleData data, _) => data.x,
                              yValueMapper: (ChartSampleData data, _) =>
                                  data.y2,
                              color: AppColors.primary50,
                            ),
                            AreaSeries(
                              dataSource: chartData!,
                              xValueMapper: (ChartSampleData data, _) => data.x,
                              yValueMapper: (ChartSampleData data, _) =>
                                  data.y3,
                              color: AppColors.primary30,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
```

**Problem**

Unfortunately, I am able to display only one series out of the three as can be seen in the app screenshot below:

[image]

**Request**

I would like to know if I am making any mistake in displaying multiple series or if there is any alternate way of displaying the series so that I am able to render the required chart as specified in the business requirement. Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Which library you have used?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil I have used syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^22.2.8

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I realised the issue. It seems syncfusion implements a Stack for multiple AreaSeries. I had to invest the order of the AreaSeries as follows:

```
series: <ChartSeries<ChartSampleData, int>>[
                            AreaSeries(
                              dataSource: chartData!,
                              xValueMapper: (ChartSampleData data, _) => data.x,
                              yValueMapper: (ChartSampleData data, _) =>
                                  data.y3,
                              color: AppColors.primary100,
                            ),
                            AreaSeries(
                              dataSource: chartData!,
                              xValueMapper: (ChartSampleData data, _) => data.x,
                              yValueMapper: (ChartSampleData data, _) =>
                                  data.y2,
                              color: AppColors.primary50,
                            ),
                            AreaSeries(
                              dataSource: chartData!,
                              xValueMapper: (ChartSampleData data, _) => data.x,
                              yValueMapper: (ChartSampleData data, _) => data.y,
                              color: AppColors.primary30,
                            ),
                          ],
```